# SaveTCL input Entry in a file and later load it

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I have developed a TCL UI with couple of inputs needs to be entered by user. First time user will enter all files path but then i wanted to save the user defined entries in a file and then later load it.
Saving is fine... i think of saving all these variables in a file, but loading it from a file needs a mapping, how it can be done ?
Any example will be helpful
[image]

Comment: Please add an example of the code that you use to save the variables.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the flexibility to define the format of the file where the contents will be stored, I'd recommend storing the contents in a way such that reading/writing maps to the keys and is order independent. This will allow you to update your UI to add/delete input fields without worrying about the order in which they are captured in the file.

For e.g., your file format could be something this:

```
Top Directory: <value>
LEF File: <value>
.
.
.
```

You'll have to carefully choose a separator between the key (label) and the value.

If this is going to be used in TCL always, you can make it simpler by storing an array in a file. This'll also speed up when you load the file to populate the entries in the UI. For e.g., your file format could be something this:

```
set inputFields("Top Directory") <value>
set inputFields("LEF File") <value>
```

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this by following code, though not very optimized.
First i am saving a input file with variable values and then reading them in same order.

```
    proc save_input_entries {} {
    global  ENTRYfilename ENTRYfilename2 ENTRYfilename3 ENTRYfilename4 ENTRYfilename5 ENTRYfilename6 ENTRYfilename7 ENTRYfilename8 ENTRYfilename9 ENTRYfilename10 ENTRYfilename11 ENTRYfilename12 ENTRYfilename13 ENTRYfilename14 ENTRYfilename15 ENTRYfilename16 ENTRYfilename17 topdir corner_dir corner_name
    set filename Input_entries.txt
    set fileId  [open $filename "w"]
    puts $fileId $ENTRYfilename
    puts $fileId $ENTRYfilename3
    puts $fileId $ENTRYfilename4
    puts $fileId $ENTRYfilename5
    puts $fileId $ENTRYfilename7
    puts $fileId $ENTRYfilename8
    puts $fileId $ENTRYfilename15
    puts $fileId $ENTRYfilename14
    puts $fileId $ENTRYfilename16
    puts $fileId $ENTRYfilename17
    close $fileId

    }


    proc load_input_entries {} {
    global  ENTRYfilename ENTRYfilename2 ENTRYfilename3 ENTRYfilename4 ENTRYfilename5 ENTRYfilename6 ENTRYfilename7 ENTRYfilename8 ENTRYfilename9 ENTRYfilename10 ENTRYfilename11 ENTRYfilename12 ENTRYfilename13 ENTRYfilename14 ENTRYfilename15 ENTRYfilename16 ENTRYfilename17

     set fp [open Input_entries.txt]
      set stuff [read $fp]
       set lines [split $stuff "\n"]
          set ENTRYfilename [lindex $lines 0]
           set ENTRYfilename3 [lindex $lines 1]
            set ENTRYfilename4 [lindex $lines 2]
            set ENTRYfilename5 [lindex $lines 3]
            set ENTRYfilename7 [lindex $lines 4]
            set ENTRYfilename8 [lindex $lines 5]
            set ENTRYfilename15 [lindex $lines 6]
            set ENTRYfilename14 [lindex $lines 7]
            set ENTRYfilename16 [lindex $lines 8]
            set ENTRYfilename17 [lindex $lines 9]
}
```